# Update UI using DispatchQueue in Firebase - SwiftUI

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

I am trying to use a `DispatchQueue` to update my UI, so when Firebase authenticates a user I can pass the newly created data to the next screen.

I have a `SignUpView` that signs up a user and then goes to a `ProfileView` upon success. The `ProfileView` allows the user to add more specific details for the application.

I have a `userSession` object that logs the user in successfully, but doesn't immediately update the UI on the next screen. This is likely because I am not properly using `DispatchQueue.main.async`, which I cannot use in the body of the `View` builder in SwiftUI.

Here's a `View` I am using to populate the username in the `ProfileView` that I get from the `SignUpView`.

**Note: When I pass to the HomeView, the username and other vitals appear. I assume this is because at that point the database is updated and I can begin to read values.**

```
struct VitalsHeaderView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if session.isLoggedIn {
                Text(session.userSession!.username)
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.501960814, green: 0.501960814, blue: 0.501960814, alpha: 1)))
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 30)
        .padding(.leading, 30)
    }
}
```

Below, you see a bad hack that doesn't work, but this is something like what I want to do. How can I use a dispatch queue to update the UI?

```
struct VitalsHeaderView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @ObservedObject var signUpViewModel = SignUpViewModel()

    func updateUI() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.session.isLoggedIn = true
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if session.isLoggedIn {
                Button(action: updateUI) {
                    Text(session.userSession!.username)
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.501960814, green: 0.501960814, blue: 0.501960814, alpha: 1)))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 30)
        .padding(.leading, 30)
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

Here's my `SessionStore` code

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import Firebase

class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn") {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.isLoggedIn, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
        }
    }
    
    var userSession: User?
    
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    func listenAuthenticationState() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                print(user.email as Any)
                let firestoreUserId = Ref.FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_USERID(userId: user.uid)
                firestoreUserId.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if let dict = document?.data() {
                        guard let decodeUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict) else { return }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           self.userSession = decodeUser
                           self.isLoggedIn = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                self.isLoggedIn = false
                self.userSession = nil
            }
        })
    }
    
    func logout() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch  {
        }
    }
    
    func unbind() {
        if let handle = handle {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        unbind()
    }
}
```

I initialize the `VitalsHeaderView` in the `ProfileView`, which is a struct above `VitalsHeaderView`.

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    
    @ObservedObject var profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var signUpViewModel = SignUpViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9058823529, green: 0.9254901961, blue: 0.968627451, alpha: 1)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9058823529, green: 0.9254901961, blue: 0.968627451, alpha: 1))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    VStack {
                        ProfileHeaderView(signUpViewModel: signUpViewModel)
                        
                        VitalsHeaderView(signUpViewModel: signUpViewModel)
      
                        ShareProfileView(profileViewModel: profileViewModel)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
    }
}
```

**NOTE: I just added (and tested) adding the signUpViewModel property to the Vitals Header View and still nothing**

Comment: Can you please also add your code for Session store and how you're initializing your `VitalsHeaderView`?

Comment: You need to make sure that `SessionStore` conforms to protocol as well as that `isLoggedIn` is a `@Published` variable.

Comment: @Zorayr done. `SessionStore` conforms to `ObservableObject`. Is that what you mean by protocol? Also, `isLoggedIn` is indeed a `@Published` property.

Comment: @David Why do you unbind on deinit?